# Export javascript object to be used as new instance

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

So I have my `menu.js` file and inside I have a `Menu` object as shown below:

```
let Menu = {
  elt: null,
  settings: {
    title: '',
  }
}
export { Menu };
```

Now, I'm wanting to use the menu object to build another menu in another file, as shown here:

```
const test = new Menu('', {
  // Empty
});
```

For some reason, it's not letting me use the export, I'm also tried `export default Menu;` with no luck, it keeps coming back with the following error:

[image]

Does anyone know the proper way to instantiate an object literal?

Comment: 1) `Menu` is not a function or a class so you cannot use `new Menu()`. 2) Is this running in a browser or Node? Are you using a bundler like Webpack?

Comment: Thanks for the details @Phil, this is running in the browser - Let's say that I want to build a function that can accept object params, would it be like `let Menu = (function() {`?

Comment: I am not using webpack.

Comment: Then you need to be using [ES6 modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) (ie `<script type="module">`) and a compatible browser

Comment: Basically, I wanted to build an object literal that I can instantiate and use for other menu objects, using possible prototypes to extend the parent object literal to the children.

Comment: Sounds like you want a [class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ES6 (AKA ES2015), JavaScript introduced classes. These work just like classes in other programming languages (if you know any), with a constructor, methods, and getters and setters (all are optional). You might want to consider switching to the following code:
`menu.js`:

```js
class Menu {
    constructor() {
        this.elt = null;
        this.settings = {
            title: ""
        }
    }

    // Other methods
}

export { Menu }
```

`main.js`:

```js
import { Menu } from "menu";

const test = new Menu();
```

However, if you want to put parameters, you can change the Menu constructor to:

```js
constructor(elt = null, settings = {
    title: ""
}) {
    this.elt = elt;
    this.settings = settings;
}
```

Then, in `main.js`,

```js
import { Menu } from "menu";

const test = new Menu("", {
    // Empty
});
```

Comment: This is just what I was looking for! Thanks @Cutewarriorlover, I was wondering how the constructor worked with object params, but this is so helpful.

Comment: Would you know anything about this error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` on the import portion?

Comment: From that, I assume that you are using Node.js. I'm not too sure exactly why it makes that error, I just know that Node.js doesn't allow the import statement like that. In that case, you would use `const { Menu } = require("./menu")`.